# d3.csv not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: d3.js

i am trying to plot a graph in D3.js taking values from a csv file but it seems to works only in Firefox, when i load the same page in IE 11 it doesn't work.

all the basic codes seems to work but d3.csv throws an error saying "access denied

i want the same code to run on IE,

Comment: I just wrote an answer but I deleted it after realising that the error would be different. So, for clarifying your issue: what's the D3 version you're using? Also, are you using a server?

Comment: Use some web server to run your code ill resolve the issue. d3.csv will work with http protocol

Comment: @GerardoFurtado i am using d3 v4, i am not using any server

Comment: In that case the answer is clear: you need to use a server. Browsers don't load files from the local file system (it's a surprise that your code worked in FF).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado thanks for the help, yep i was surprised too